# Laravel Email Verification Disable & Enable with one touch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there anyway we can enable / disable email verification dynamically when a users register?

I think, in order to set email verification, we should set `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` on the **routes** and in the **User model**, we should set  `class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail`

But, is there any simple way to do this dynamically?
So, let's say we set enable / disable in admin panel.
And according to it, can we set enable / disable in front auth page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply manipulate the `email_verified_at` column in the `users` table.

I suggest using an observer :

```sh
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

You can use config or database to determine whether to use verification email or not.

**`UserObserver`**

```php
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the user "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        // Let's say you use config

        if (config('app.email_verification') == false) {
            $user->email_verified_at = now();
            $user->save();
        }
    }

    //

}
```

To determine email delivery, you can override `sendEmailVerificationNotification` in the User model:

```
/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    if (config('app.email_verification')) {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }
}
```

And add the next line before the **User class** definition:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
```

---

#### Update

To keep `email_verified_at` as `null`, you can remove the observer, then update your `Auth::routes` like this:

**web.php**

```php
Auth::routes([
    'verify' => config('app.email_verification')
]);


Route::group([
    'middleware' => [config('app.email_verification') ? 'verified' : null]
], function () {

    // protected routes

    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So in this case, if email verify function is disabled, then all users will be as verified? Is there any way to keep email_verified_at as null and pass them ?

Comment: @lovecoding yes, remove observer, then update your route. Answer updated.

Comment: Then How about verified middleware? Maybe your first answer is best option?

Comment: @lovecoding you can make conditional too

Comment: How to do conditional ?